# Where should .sh/bash scripts be placed when using CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

that would be the 'correct' place/way to use?  Still very new...  Basically trying to port an app to CakePHP and update it.  A lot of the functionality of the program is in bash scripts.

Like what CakePHP has forced me to learn regarding MVC model, and couldn't find really any info on proper way to use bash scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`app/Console` would be the appropriate location.